# How to collect the result values using while?

Tags: python

I have a question of while in python.
How to collect the result values using while?

```
ColumnCount_int = 3
while ColumnCount_int > 0 :
    ColumnCount_text = str('<colspec colnum="'+ str(ColumnCount_int) +'"' ' ' 'colname="'+ str(ColumnCount_int) + '">')
    Blank_text = ""
    Blank_text = Blank_text + ColumnCount_text
    ColumnCount_int = ColumnCount_int - 1
    print(Blank_text)
```

result shows as below

```
<colspec colnum="3" colname="3">
<colspec colnum="2" colname="2">
<colspec colnum="1" colname="1">
```

but i want to collect all result like as below

```
<colspec colnum="3" colname="3"><colspec colnum="2" colname="2"><colspec colnum="1" colname="1">
```

Would you tell me which part wrong is ?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want a new line between each printed result? Or that you want to collect them all into a single variable?

Comment: To collect them all into a single value, cause i will insert this result into other.

Comment: As a side note: I'm pretty sure that `colspec` didn't exist in any of the old versions of HTML that allowed unclosed tags, so your code is generating invalid markup. Also, is there a reason you don't want to use an HTML document generator, instead of creating the text manually?

Comment: it's used in dita not html but i guess it doesn't matter in this code though. Thank you for help.

Comment: OK, then you're generating invalid DITA markup, not invalid HTML markup. Both languages use the same CALS model for tables. And, since DITA is XML, you're even less likely to get away with it—people write HTML parsers with a "quirks mode" that accepts buggy HTML, but nobody does that for XML languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix the code by following where `Blank_text = ""` is moved before `while loop` and `print(Blank_text)` is called after the `loop`.

(**Note**: *since `Blank_text` accumulates, variable name changed to `accumulated_text` as suggested in the comment*):

```
ColumnCount_int = 3
accumulated_text = "" # variable name changed, used instead of Blank_text
while ColumnCount_int > 0 :
    ColumnCount_text = str('<colspec colnum="'+ str(ColumnCount_int) +'"' ' ' 'colname="'+ str(ColumnCount_int) + '">')
    accumulated_text = accumulated_text + ColumnCount_text
    ColumnCount_int = ColumnCount_int - 1
print(accumulated_text)
```

Result:

```
<colspec colnum="3" colname="3"><colspec colnum="2" colname="2"><colspec colnum="1" colname="1">
```

## Update:

However, same result can be from following in little compact way with `.join`:

```
result = ''.join('<colspec colnum="{0}" colname="{1}">'.format(i,i) for i in range(3,0,-1))
print(result)
```

Comment: I'd also suggest changing the name of `Blank_text` to something like `accumulated_text`: it starts out as the empty string but it doesn't stay that way for long. Good variable names are important.

Comment: @Nick thanks for suggestion (*edited*). I was trying to just fix it, mentioned in `comment`.

Answer (score 1):

Try appending it to the new list i created `l`, then do [`''.join(l)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_join.htm) to output it in one line :

```
l = []
ColumnCount_int = 3
while ColumnCount_int > 0 :
      ColumnCount_text = str('<colspec colnum="'+ str(ColumnCount_int) +'"' ' ' 'colname="'+ str(ColumnCount_int) + '">')
      Blank_text = ColumnCount_text
      ColumnCount_int = ColumnCount_int - 1
      l.append(Blank_text)
print(''.join(l))
```

Output:

```
<colspec colnum="3" colname="3"><colspec colnum="2" colname="2"><colspec colnum="1" colname="1">
```

## Shorter Way

Also try this:

```
l = []
ColumnCount_int = 3
while ColumnCount_int > 0 :
      l.append(str('<colspec colnum="'+str(ColumnCount_int)+'"'' ''colname="'+str(ColumnCount_int)+'">'))
      ColumnCount_int-=1
print(''.join(l))
```

Output:

```
<colspec colnum="3" colname="3"><colspec colnum="2" colname="2"><colspec colnum="1" colname="1">
```